# Creating short examples for CRAN package

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran, roxygen2

I'm currently building a package that I hope to upload to CRAN. The examples I've included in my help documentation currently take some time to check (~12min in total), and I'm aware that this can be an issue when trying to load on CRAN. While I could make my examples run faster, I'm worried this will make them less meaningful for users reading the help files. Is there a way to include some fast (but less meaningful) examples that will be checked by CRAN but won't be visible to users in the help documentation?

I'm using devtools and roxygen2 to write my documentation, so it would be great to get an answer using these tools if possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your examples take a long time to run,  you may want to simplify them as much as you can, and profile the R code for efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you would like to do some unit testing, which is a very good idea when working with more complex packages. Check out the `testthat` package ([article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf), [source](https://github.com/hadley/testthat)).

Short and purely technical examples that are needed to ensure correct operation of your package, but not very relevant to the end user, would then go into a separate folder `myPackage/tests`. These will automatically be run every time you build the package, but will not be included in the documentation files.

The recommended solution is to make a file called `myPackage/tests/run-all.R`:

```
library(testthat)
library(myPackage)
test_package("myPackage")
```

then put all the testing code in `myPackage/tests/testthat`, e.g. `myPackage/tests/testthat/foo.R`:

```
context("Basic operation")

test_that("Default execution", {
    a <- 4
    b <- 34
    expect_equal(myFunction(a, b), a + b)
})
```

The reason for putting the tests in `myPackage/tests/testthat` rather than directly in `myPackage/tests` is that `myPackage/tests/testthat` will be included in the final package (albeit in a different folder) which allows the user to also run the tests. `myPackage/tests` will not be copied to the final package.

Comment: Tests should go in `tests/testthat`. The old `inst/tests` will be deprecated in a future version.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that, but have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

See the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions), section 2.1.1, `example` subsection. You can enclose your more heavy examples into `\dontrun` and they will not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is CRAN loading, you should use `\donttest{}` command to prevent running the examples on CRAN. Note that the examples will still run when the user type `example(xx)`

Comment: `\donttest` is no longer useful because that code is now tested :/